# Session auth_user_id not correct in django

Tags: python, django, session

In my views.py, in some view, i have `uid = request.user.id`  this gives the id of the user that is logged in right now which i display on my template and is coming out to be correct. But the same id should also be sent to the session as auth_user_id which is according to sessions table /admin/sessions/ here is not getting displayed. No matter which user is logged in, it always shows `{u'_auth_user_hash': u'ca7e738308ed261de83fe3c80c9a4657b37e8c81', u'_auth_user_id': u'2', u'_auth_user_backend': u'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend'}`. uid=2 is the superuser(admin) in my table. I can't seem to figure out why this is happening? Any ideas?
Also only one session is stored in the session table.

Comment: How is the `/admin/sessions/` view defined?

Comment: It is not a view that I have defined explicitly..it is the default django admin site..I have just registered imported Session from django.contrib.sessions.models in my admin.py and registered it by making a class SessionAdmin(model.ModelAdmin)....and registering it like admin.site.register(Session, SessionAdmin)

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be with your session store. If you’re using the database backend, the django_session database table keeps on growing. Django adds a row to the `django_session` database table. Django updates this row each time the session data changes. If the user logs out manually, Django deletes the row. But if the user does not log out, the row never gets deleted. 
Remove all the entries form the table and try again . use this command in python shell

```
python manage.py shell(to open shell)
from django.contrib.sessions.models import Session
Session.objects.all().delete()
```